# Why does an empty block exists whereas an empty inline does not?

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I was learning about floats and clearfix. So if all the elements of a container are floats then the container shrinks, and to have height, container must have a non-float element. So when an empty inline is inserted into the container, nothing happens, but when an empty block is added, the container gains height. I don't understand why this happens as neither block nor inline have any content and probably should behave identically. Furthermore, why is the inline element not at bottom (when it has content) and it's clear property is set to "both". I am seeing [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tC4PIlEz_o)

```css
ul {
  width: calc((2rem + 300px) * 4);
  /* allows for 4 columns */
  margin: 1rem auto;
  /* center the gallery */
  border: 1px solid hsl(0, 50%, 50%);
  background-color: hsla(0, 50%, 80%, 0.2);
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 1rem;
}


/* li:last-child {
            float: none;
          } */

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: inline;
}

p {}
```

```html
<ul class="clearfix">
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400?image=70" alt="picsum" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400?image=10" alt="picsum" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400?image=20" alt="picsum" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400?image=30" alt="picsum" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400?image=40" alt="picsum" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400?image=50" alt="picsum" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400?image=60" alt="picsum" /></li>
</ul>
<p>Paragraph that comes after the ul.</p>
```

Comment: clear can only be applied to block element

Comment: Okay, but if we ignore clear property on inline elements, this inline element should have existed at least halfway where it did when it has content and the container should have gained half helight, like when it gains full height when an empty block is add with clear on both sides

Comment: your inline element has no content so it like it doesn't exist at all. When adding content to it, it's a different story and the content will wrap around the floated element and you container will grow to the position of that content

Comment: so why does the container gain height if we replace empty "inline" with empty "block"

Comment: it doesn't gain any height either with an empty inline or empty block: https://jsfiddle.net/xjhLq1ar/ ... the only case where it gain height is when you clear float

Comment: but it shouldn't right, setting clear to 'both' of 'block' should have just placed it at bottom, but since it's empty, it should to be considered non-existant

Comment: if you clear the float then the container will have the height of your float element and that block can be considered non-existant but its purpose is to clear float. It doesn't affect the height but it does clear the float to make the container grow with the float element (this is the purpose of clear). If you don't clear then nothing will happen because your element is empty